# customize the look of dynamically created DIVs

Tags: javascript, css

The script creates a random number of divs (in range 20-40) and puts some text in every single div. The script calculates the width of divs so that they fit in a single row. The height should be equal to the width - every div must be a square. Here's the code:

```js
var quantity = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 20 + 1)) + 20;


for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.className = "part";
  elem.id = 'p' + i;
  document.getElementById("scale").appendChild(elem);
}

var parts = document.getElementsByClassName("part");

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  parts[i].style.fontSize = (500 / quantity) + 'px';
  parts[i].style.lineHeight = (460 / quantity) + 'px';

  parts[i].textContent = ("block #" + (i + 1));
}

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  parts[i].style.height = parts[i].style.width;
}

let text = document.getElementById('txt');
text.textContent = 'BLOCKS: ' + quantity;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#scale {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 1px;
}

.part {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #a9cce3;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="scale"> </div>

<div id='txt'> </div>
```

The first problem is the divs are not always square. The second problem is I can't properly set the font size depending on a div size, so text fits a div. I think that's the worst solution

```
parts[i].style.fontSize = (500 / quantity) + 'px';
parts[i].style.lineHeight = (460 / quantity) + 'px';
```

Comment: Why are you using overflow hidden when your children size is exceeding the parent limit.

Comment: In your current example were you to reduce the font to fit the div with no wrapping it would surely be too small to see, is that really what you want?

Comment: you should use computed style to get the width

Comment: if blocks are really small it's ok if the font's too small to be seen

Comment: Check the answer may be will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems with the code:

1. To get element with use `.clientWidth` because `style.width` can be accessed when you have set that but in your code, I couldn't see you are doing so.
2. Second use font size in per cent, I don't think line-height is required. To make it centre use CSS as in example follows.

Use following:

```js
var quantity = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 20 + 1)) + 20;


for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.className = "part";
  elem.id = 'p' + i;
  document.getElementById("scale").appendChild(elem);
}

var parts = document.getElementsByClassName("part");

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  parts[i].style.fontSize = (500 / quantity) + '%';
  parts[i].style.lineHeight = (460 / quantity) + '%';

  parts[i].textContent = ("block #" + (i + 1));
}

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  parts[i].style.height = parts[i].clientWidth + "px";
}

let text = document.getElementById('txt');
text.textContent = 'BLOCKS: ' + quantity;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#scale {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 1px;
}

.part {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #a9cce3;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="scale"> </div>

<div id='txt'> </div>
```

Or if you don't want to use your text font to be reduced like this use following:

```
.part {
      display: table-cell;
      background-color: #a9cce3;
      padding: 3px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 2px;
      overflow: hidden;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
       overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap; 
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution! But could you please tell is it a good idea to use this line `parts[i].style.fontSize = (500 / quantity)`. I don't know why 500 works, I got it just setting different random values

Comment: It's relating to the size of the body. document.body.clientWidth